# Using an identity to simplify the sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, logarithms

So I ran into this problem today. It asks me to use an identity to simplify the sum.

> > $$\sum_{j=7}^{27}\ln\left(\frac{j+1}{j}\right)$$

I have no idea where to start. I don't know any identity that fits this formation. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can also look at the product; since $$A=\sum_{j=7}^{27}\ln\left(\frac{j+1}{j}\right)$$ then $$e^A=\prod_{j=7}^{27}\frac{j+1}{j}=\frac{8\times 9\times 10\times 11 \cdots \times 28}{7\times 8\times 9\times 10\times 11 \cdots \times 27}=\frac{(8\times 9\times 10\times 11 \cdots\times 27) \times 28}{7\times (8\times 9\times 10\times 11 \cdots \times 27)}$$ and notice how easily it simplifies. What is left is $$e^A=\frac{28}{7}=4$$ So, $A=2\log(2)$

Comment: thats imo more intuitive than identities. nice!

Answer (score 4):

***Hint:***

$$ \ln \dfrac a b = \ln a - \ln b$$

Comment: Thanks... I simplified it to ln(28)-ln(7), is this the right answer?

Comment: You can go one step further. $ \ln 28 = \ln (4 \times 7) =  \ln 4 + \ln 7 $

Comment: I simplified it down to 2*ln(2)

Comment: @user1763899: I think you are done.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$\ln\left(\frac{j+1}{j}\right)=\ln(j+1)-\ln(j)$$

This for $j>0$.